# Adminhtml Modal Layout

Tags: admin, adminhtml, controllers, forms

I have a tabbed edit screen for my module. Inside one of the tabs, I launch a modal view which is another, related, form. However, I'm unsure how to render the layout without the header/footer, but retaining the styles.

Is there a way to do this?

```
/**
 * Runs the procedure for rendering a modal view to the screen
 *
 * @param Company_Module_Block_* block
 * @return void
 * @author Dan Hanly
 **/
public function renderModal($block)
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_addContent($block);
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

To clarify; within my Modal form, I wish to render a layout with a title and form, but without the adminhtml main menu, header or footer. Just the layout by itself. I obviously want to retain styles so that my form's styling matches others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$this->loadLayout();
```

With

```
$this->loadLayout('popup');
```

**[EDIT]**

and to remove the footer try this

```
$this->getLayout()->unsetBlock('footer');
```

Comment: Wow, just like that. the footer is still there though :)

Comment: @DanHanly. See my edit. I didn't test it but it might work.

Comment: Is this before or after the loadLayout line? Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: After loadLayout. but, like I said. I didn't test it. I just knew how to remove the header and menu.